# PDFdictionary and unicode (and Java)

Tags: java, pdf, unicode, itext

I have a text editing program. It exports the document it creates into PDF.

It also saves a series of strings into PDFDictionary that enables it to reopen document it creates.

For font in PDF as well as in my program I use BookAntiqua, extracted .ttf from my Win7 system. It can display hose fonts without any problems.

However, I have a problem. Characters which my users will use will common be šđčćž and ŠĐČĆŽ.

When I first enter them in my program, they are displayed properly. When I save it to PDF and open it with Adobe Reader, they are displayed properly. However, when I load that PDF back into my program, they are either displayed as ⎕ or not displayed at all.

I guess the problem is in the way I populate PDFDictionary. I tried to do something like `string.replace("Ž", "/u017D");` and `string.replace("Đ", "\u017D");`, but it didn't help.
Opening my PDF from eclipse, I noticed that instead of saving "Ž" like this: "/u0017D" it was still saved like "Ž", and some of other problematic letters were missing (inside of PDFDictionary, all of that).

What I want to know is how to print e.g. character "Ž" into PDFDictionary in a way that once read by my program will be displayed in e.g. JTextArea as character "Ž".

EDIT: All PDF handling is done with iText!

Code:

when saving:

```
PDFobject = new PdfString("šđčćž ŠĐČĆŽ");
PDFName index =  new PdfName("1");

dictionary.put(index, object);
```

when opening (loading):

```
PDFName index = new PdfName("1");
PDFObject line = dictionary.get(index);
String string = line.toString();

JTextArea abc= new JTextArea();
abc.setText(string);
```

If change a line into this: `PDFobject = new PdfString("šđčćž ŠĐČĆŽ", "UTF-8");`, I still get some random gibberish as an output...

Comment: What's a PDFDictionary?  I don't think an explanation is possible without understanding what you mean by that.  Is that a class of yours or a library?

Comment: It's an PDF object, part of PDF.

Comment: So, what exact char arrays are you getting when you do "dictionary.get(index)"? As in, if you round-trip the string `"\u017D"` by saving it into a PDF file and then loading it again from the Dictionary, do you get a single-character string back, where the only character is the one that you entered? Or, to put this another way, you need to look at what code points you're saving and loading first, then figure out why they're rendered wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode your characters properly.  [Unicode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html) is a standard that's shared by Java and PDF.  I'd recommend explicitly encoding your text as UTF-8 so both will handle it.

Comment: How do I do that? Coudl you tell my which methods or classes to use (or what is required)?

Comment: Better start reading about Unicode.  I don't know how you've created your PDF.  If you're using XSL-FO or iText, you should be able to do it.  They both support Unicode.

Comment: I created it with iText...
I can save it as UTF-8, but it doesn't help, although it changes output a bit (some random characters)...

Comment: I edited the question. Your techinque doesn't work, can you apply something else to my pseudo-code that might work?

Comment: It's not my technique; it's how encoding needs to be done.  You're not doing it correctly.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html

Answer (score 2):

The (IDE) editor uses an encoding and the java compiler uses an encoding. Both have to be set to the same encoding. I use UTF-8 for international support. Then the compiled java (.class, .jar) uses Unicode internally.

Another way to ensure the right encoding, is to use Unicode escapes like `\u017D`.

iText has its own encodings. And then there is the font that must be capable to display the chars. iText can use one of PDFs own fonts, or an embedded font (which increases the PDF's size with the used subset).

No answer, but I think you need to look in the [iText](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/) API, DocumentFont, `charExists` for instance, using character encodings in `createFont` or such.

Comment: +1 for IDE explanation, I didn't told for him(forgot). It has affects at `PdfString("šđčćž ŠĐČĆŽ");`!!!